# Replacing a value of a JavaScript array object using js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JavaScript array as follows

```
var array = [{"month": 1, "days": 31},{"month": 2, "days": 2},{"month": 3, "days": 21}]
```

I need to replace days value of month 1 to 12 as follows

```
var array = [{"month": 1, "days": 12},{"month": 2, "days": 2},{"month": 3, "days": 21}]
```

How can I get this. I tried the following way. But it's not working

```
var val = array.indexOf(1);
for(var i=0; i <array .length; i++ )
{
if(val != -1)
array.month[val].push({month:1, days:12 }); 
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Are you just trying to change the number of days in month 1? As you can see from the different answers, people are interpreting what you want quite differently.

Answer (score 4):

You can `.map()` your array and change the mapped object when `month: 1` appears like so:

```js
var array = [{"month": 1, "days": 31},{"month": 2, "days": 2},{"month": 3, "days": 21}];

var new_array = array.map(({month, days}) => month === 1 ? {month, days: 12} : {month, days});
console.log(new_array);
```

Alternatively, if you wish to change your array in place, you can use `.filter()` and then change the days attribute on the filtered objects like so:

```js
var array = [{"month": 1, "days": 31},{"month": 2, "days": 2},{"month": 3, "days": 21}];

array.filter(({month}) => month === 1).forEach(o => o.days = 12);
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'of' keyword also to achieve this, however what you want to change totally depends on u, here is a little example:

```js
var array = [{"month": 1, "days": 31},{"month": 2, "days": 2},{"month": 3, "days": 21}];
for(var i of array){if(i.month === 1){i.days = 12}}
console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it may just be an example, but avoid using array as it is too close to Array, an object of JavaScript. I will use arr for array.

Just to change the value of days in month 1 to 12:

`arr[0].days = 12;`

However, if you need the ability to change any given month's day value, try a function:

```
  function changeDays(month, days) {
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i){
      if(arr[i].month == month) arr[i].days = days;
    };
  };

  changeDays(1, 12); // changes 31 days to 12 days in month 1
```

The other answers from Nick and TrickOrTreat are more elegant, and Parth's answer assumes you need to search for a days value instead of month value. My solution is closest to your example and it makes more sense to me that you would want to search by month. But hey, you know better than any of us what your requirements are!

Comment: This is not working correctly. Your if condition doesn't do the checking. Instead its just assigning month so that all the months in the json array becomes the same

Comment: Thank you, tharindu. Stupid assignment vs. comparison typo. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `forEach` function to accomplish this,

```
var array = [{"month": 1, "days": 31},{"month": 2, "days": 2},{"month": 3, "days": 21}]

array.forEach(e=>{

  if(e.month == 1)
    e.days = 12;
});

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var array = [{
  "month": 1,
  "days": 31
}, {
  "month": 2,
  "days": 2
}, {
  "month": 3,
  "days": 21
}];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (array[i].days === 31) {
    array[i].days = 12
  }
}
console.log(array)
```

You can replace the particular element by identifying it.